# StgOpenStorage and StgCreateDocFile always return STG_E_ INVALIDNAME

Tags: c++, winapi, mfc, com

I encountered a very strange issue. When Win32 API StgOpenStorage or StgCreateDocFile is called, I get error STG_E_ INVALIDNAME. But actually the name is correct.

I wrote a very simple MFC application, click a button and run code as below:

```
const WCHAR* pWchar = L"D:\\Test\\Test.rsh";
CComPtr<IStorage> pStorage = NULL;
HRESULT hr = StgCreateDocFile(pWchar, STGM_READWRITE | STGM_CREATE | STGM_SHARE_EXCLUSIVE | STGM_TRANSACTED, 0, &pStorage);
```

The file path is correct, but hr will be STG_E_ INVALIDNAME.

This issue only exists on certain PC, in another PC, this part of code could work well. I doubt the environment has some problems, but I could not find out any evidence. Anyone could provide some comments?

Many thanks.

Comment: Does that directory already exist?

Comment: Yes, the directory exists.

Comment: From [STGM Constants: STGM_TRANSACTED](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa380337.aspx): *"The COM compound file implementation of IStorage does not support transacted streams, which means that streams can be opened only in direct mode [...]"* - I don't see how that would provoke this particular error code, but it may be worth trying to use direct mode instead of transacted.